how to use gunicorn to launch two flask services with different workers?
On my server, I can start two services like this:
gunicorn -w 2 server:app1
gunicorn -w 4 server:app2

But this requires two lines of commands. Is there a method that I can use only one command to establish the serivces of app1 and app2, where app1 has 2 workers and app2 has 4 workers?
Here both of app1 and app2 is expected to use same port.

Are app1 and app2 identical? Because if they use the same port how do you distinguish requests?

@Lenntror I can accept different ports, is there any method to do this?

I would personally recommend using a service like supervisor.
With supervisor you can create two configuration files for each of your applications and supervisor will take care of automatically launching them concurrently.
First conf file
[program:app1]
command=/path/to/your/app/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 2 server:app1
directory=/path/to/your/app
user=UNIX_username
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

Second conf file:
[program:app2]
command=/path/to/your/app/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 4 server:app2
directory=/path/to/your/app
user=UNIX_username
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true

Then:
sudo supervisorctl reload

